# How to judge the function is kernel function or not in program method?

Tags: built-in-symbols

### I found the behavoir have changed. All symbol in `` System` `` is *kernel funtion*(include those your custom funtion)

`` System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ[Plot] ``

> `True`

---

If you run

```
<<GeneralUtilities`;GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[ShearingMatrix]
```

You will get the definition of `ShearingMatrix`.But when you run

```
<<GeneralUtilities`;GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[UnitStep]
```

You will get a information that the `UnitStep` is a *kernel function*.Can we make a custom function,like `KernelFunctionQ`, to judge the function in context of `` System` `` is a *kernel function* or not?

Comment: Wouldn't `PrintDefinitions[PrintDefinitions]` tell you how that's implemented?

Comment: @ilian Wow,I have not seen your comment before this.I do it just now.Get a chunk code.Maybe it deserve dig.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @yode From my experience `HasOwnCodeQ`, `HasDownCodeQ`, `HasSubCodeQ`, `HasUpCodeQ`, `HowPrintCodeQ` will only return true if it's implemented internally. They don't catch `OwnValues`, `DownValue`, `SubValues`, `UpValues,` or `FormatValues`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 No,see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133740/21532)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [wonderful comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129978/how-to-judge-the-function-is-kernel-function-or-not-in-program-method#comment351078_129978) I have to say.I have not think about it before this.As the promption,I get into the page of `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``,Then I click `Definitions`->`KernelPlaceholderDefs`,I have got this information:

```
KernelPlaceholderDefs[sym_Symbol] := If[!HasAnyCodesQ[sym],
    {},
    DeleteCases[Null][
        {
            If[HasOwnCodeQ[sym],
                HoldPattern[sym] :> $KernelFunctionPlaceholder
   ],
   If[HasDownCodeQ[sym],
    HoldPattern[sym[___]] :> $KernelFunctionPlaceholder
            ],
            If[HasSubCodeQ[sym],
                HoldPattern[sym[___][___]] :> $KernelFunctionPlaceholder
   ],
   If[HasUpCodeQ[sym],
    HoldPattern[_[___, sym, ___]] :> $KernelFunctionPlaceholder
            ],
            If[HasPrintCodeQ[sym],
                HoldPattern[Format[sym, _]] :> $KernelFunctionPlaceholder
            ]
        }
    ]
];

Attributes[KernelPlaceholderDefs] := {HoldAll};
```

So the function `` System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ `` can judge the function is kernel function or not.Maybe is all of in a local file `` GeneralUtilities`PackageScope`$KernelFunctionPlaceholder `` but I don't know how to open it,we can get it all by following code:

```
kernelFunctions = 
  Quiet[Select[
    ToExpression[CanonicalName[EntityList["WolframLanguageSymbol"]]], 
    System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ]]
```

> {$AssertFunction,Identity,Identity,Abort,AbortProtect,Abs,AbsArg,AbsoluteFileName,AbsoluteTime,AbsoluteTiming,Accumulate,Accuracy,Activate,AcyclicGraphQ,AddTo,AdjacencyList,AdjacencyMatrix,AffineHalfSpace,AffineSpace,AiryAi,AiryAiPrime,AiryBi,AiryBiPrime,AlgebraicIntegerQ,AlgebraicNumber,AlgebraicNumberDenominator,AlgebraicNumberNorm,AlgebraicNumberTrace,AlgebraicUnitQ,AllTrue,...}

A total of $\color{red}{1341}$ *kernel function* that we can not use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to get it's definition.And we can see the kernel function is classifid 5 kinds by WR,such as `HasOwnCodeQ`,`HasDownCodeQ`,`HasSubCodeQ`,`HasUpCodeQ` and `HasPrintCodeQ`.