# How does FindGeneratingFunction work?

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion, combinatorics, implementation-details

How do [`FindGeneratingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeneratingFunction.html) and [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) work?

How might one implement similar functionality from scratch in Mathematica?  I am looking for a description of a reasonable algorithm, not necessarily code.  I am more interested in any computer algebra methods to solve this problem than in the specifics of the particular implementation Mathematica uses.

Comment: Did you see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html... there are some references also.

Comment: For FindSequenceFunction I'd guess that you just try the simplest polynomial fit... But I have no idea, really

Comment: [This Generating Functions MIT Course Notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2005/readings/ln11.pdf) contain the basic recipes and some examples how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

In `Mathematica`,some function is classified as *kernel function*,such as `Sin`,`UnitStep` or `Abs` and so on.We can use `` System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ `` to judge it is *kernel function* or not,I have metioned it in this post [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133403/21532) recently.If the function is not a *kernel function*.Since they all are not,we can use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to get some some information of what you want.

```
<<GeneralUtilities`;GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[FindGeneratingFunction]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-13-07-03-03.png

We can see the work fuction is call a name of `findGeneratingFunctionParser`,click on it.You will get its page of definition,then you will see `findGeneratingFunctionDispatcher`,`findGeneratingFunctionPoints` and `iFunctionSpace`.We can know it find generation function in 5 case:
http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-13-07-09-55.png

You can use same method to find some information for `FindSequenceFunction`.Those information is more useful to you maybe.It's very clear.