# How to find all function which cannot be ToExpression?

Tags: warning-messages, built-in-symbols

If you use `ToExpression` directly like this

```
ToExpression /@ Names["*`*"]
```

> [image]

You will get a chunk error information.I try to find which function make this behavior,so I make a custom `cache` to collect all function be executed:

```
tem = <||>;
cache := (AssociateTo[tem, # -> #]; #) &
ToExpression[cache[#]] & /@ Names["*`*"]
```

The last of tem is

```
Last[tem]
```

> ```
> DataPaclets`FinancialDataDump`channel10
> ```

This function abort the caculation:

```
ToExpression[Last[tem]]
```

> [image]

But I don't know which function result to this

> [image]

In this post,I try to find all function which can not get a **Normally** result(Such as `ToExpression["Plot"]` get `Plot` or `ToExpression["Sin"]` get `Sin`,then this define a normal case,and the `ToExpression["$Version"]` wil not give `$Version` but give its value,I will think that as *unnormal* here).How to implement it?

Comment: Have you looked at using `Check`?

Comment: Assigned Symbols evaluate to something other than themselves, e.g. `foo = 1; ToExpression[foo]` returns `1`.  Do you wish to consider that a *normal result*?

Comment: @m_goldberg Of course,I have.But the `Check` can help a little here I think,such as that output of `Buzz`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have uptate your case in the post. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) in *Mathematica* is a tricky business.  This makes the definition of a "normal result" tricky as well.  This response will point out some of those difficulties and provide some tools to deal with them.

**Core Issue**

The core issue is that naive use of `ToExpression` to convert a string into a symbol will cause the symbol to be evaluated.  For example:

```
ToExpression["Red"]
(* RGBColor[1, 0, 0] *)
```

Notice how it returns the value of the symbol `Red` instead of the symbol itself.

**Loading Symbols Can Be Dangerous**

Thus, when we evaluate `` ToExpression /@ Names["*`*"] `` we are evaluating a very large number of symbols.  This is a dangerous operation.  Many symbols are never meant to be evaluated in isolation.

The question gives us a few examples.  Let us look at the first.  In a fresh kernel session (mine is V11.0.1), evaluate:

```
Quantity;

"CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`AbsorbNumbers" // ToExpression

(* 
  During evaluation of In[1]:= Quantity::nonopt: Options expected
  (instead of CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`opts:OptionsPattern[])
  beyond position 2 in Quantity[...]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
*)
```

The problem is that `AbsorbNumbers` has a pattern as its value.  By itself, that pattern contains an evaluation leak which generates a (harmless) message.

This example might be harmless, but many symbols are not so harmless.  Evaluating an arbitrary symbol might:

- trigger auto-loading of a package
- produce output
- download from the Internet
- attempt to access or modify cloud objects
- load or flush caches
- change system settings
- load large expressions into memory
- play audio or make sounds
- re-evaluate expressions that were evaluated earlier within a session

These actions are not entirely safe.

**Should We Detect Such Failures?**

It might be possible to assemble a list of symbols that cause trouble.  For example, we could use `Check` to identify symbol evaluations which issue messages and `CheckAll` to find evaluations that `Throw` or `Abort`.  But such tests are too late -- whatever harm the evaluation caused is already done.

Therefore, I suggest that it is too harmful to attempt to evaluate all symbols in the system.  We need another approach.

**An Alternate Approach**

It is safer to inspect symbols *without* evaluating them.  We can easily prevent the evaluation like this:

```
ToExpression["Red", InputForm, HoldComplete]

(* HoldComplete[Red] *)
```

This, however, does not tell us anything about `Red` itself.  We can use functions `OwnValues`, `DownValues` and `UpValues` to get some information about symbols:

```
OwnValues[Red]
(* {HoldPattern[Red]:> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]} *)

DownValues[AbsoluteCurrentValues]
(* {{HoldPattern[AbsoluteCurrentValue[System`FEDump`option_]] :> ..., ... }*)

UpValues[Capitalize]
(* {HoldPattern[Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry[Capitalize]] :> {1,1}} *)
```

We can combine these functions with `ToExpression` to get information about a symbol in string form in a *relatively* safe manner:

```
ToExpression["Red", InputForm, OwnValues]
(* {HoldPattern[Red]:> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]} *)
```

However, for the case at hand there is a problem with these information functions.  They are `HoldAll` but not `HoldAllComplete`.  So if we are going to scan across all symbols, there is still a chance for potentially dangerous evaluation leaks.

I prefer to use a set of undocumented (V11.0.1) information functions:

```
Names["System`Private`Has*Q"] // Map[Symbol /* SymbolName]
(* {HasAnyCodesQ,HasAnyEvaluationsQ,HasDelayedValueQ,HasDownCodeQ,
    HasDownEvaluationsQ,HasImmediateValueQ,HasNoCodesQ,
    HasNoEvaluationsQ,HasOwnCodeQ,HasOwnEvaluationsQ,
    HasPrintCodeQ,HasSubCodeQ,HasSubEvaluationsQ,
    HasUpCodeQ,HasUpEvaluationsQ} *)
```

These functions have a couple of advantages that are relevant to the current discussion.  First, they are `HoldAllComplete` so they will prevent as many evaluation leaks as is possible from high-level code.  Second, they are aware of built-in kernel definitions that are invisible to `DownValues` et al.

Here is a useful helper function:

```
info =
  Names["System`Private`Has*Q"] //
  Map[StringReplace[SymbolName[#], "Has"~~n__~~"Q" :> n] -> #&[Symbol[#]]&] //
  Apply[Hold] //
  Replace[#, s_Symbol :> ToExpression[#2[1], InputForm, s], {2}] &[#, Slot]& //
  Replace[_[r__] :> Function[Null, <| "Name" -> #, r |>, HoldAllComplete]];
```

We can use it like this:

```
info["Sin"]
(* <| Name -> "Sin"
    , AnyCodes -> True
    , AnyEvaluations -> True
    , DelayedValue -> False
    , DownCode -> True
    , DownEvaluations -> True
    , ImmediateValue -> False
    ...
    |>
*)
```

This tells us that `Sin` has built-in down-value definitions even though `DownValues[Sin]` returns nothing.

Armed with this helper, we can ask various questions:

```
$allInfo = info /@ Names["*`*"] // Dataset;
```

What are all the symbols with no evaluation rules at all?

```
$allInfo[Select[#NoEvaluations &], "Name"]
```

What are all the symbols that have built-in function definitions?

```
$allInfo[Select[#DownCode&], "Name"]
```

What are all the symbols that have function definitions but are not built-in?

```
$allInfo[Select[#DownEvaluations && ! #DownCode &], "Name"]
```

---

**Addendum: Some Debugging Tricks**

OK, so evaluating lots of symbols is dangerous and we should not do it.  Fine.  But the question remains: how can we identify which symbols are causing problems?

Unfortunately, the problematic evaluations take different forms, so no one technique will find them all.  But here are a few tricks that will often bear fruit.

*Debugger: Break At Messages*

We can use the debugger to find the source of the first message.  Turn on the debugger and check the *Break at Messages* setting.  Then evaluate:

```
ToExpression /@ Names["*`*"]
```

The debugger will stop at the first message.  The stack window shows:

[image: debugger screenshot]

We can see `` ToExpression[CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`AbsorbNumbers] `` on the stack.

*Debugger: Forced Break*

Next, let's consider the "Buzz" that appears as output when scanning the symbols.  This is not accompanied by a message, so the "break at messages" trick is not going to work.  The "Buzz" is very strange because it actually generates output and causes a beep to sound from the speaker.  Since it generates output, we might guess that it is using `Print`.  So let us use `Trace` to set up a trap for calls to `Print` and force the debugger to stop there:

```
Trace[ToExpression /@ Names["*`*"]
, _Print?(RuntimeTools`BreakNow[]&)
, TraceInternal -> True
]
```

[image: "Buzz" Trace screenshot]

We see that `` GeneralUtilities`Buzz `` is the culprit.  What a strange symbol.  It should probably be a function... but we may have just stumbled upon a nice tool for finding evaluation leaks.

If the culprit had not been using `Print`, we might have tried other guesses like `CellPrint`, or even `Play` or `Beep` to try to catch the sound.

*Brute Force*

We got lucky in the last case because we correctly guessed that the buzzing was caused by a call to `Print`.  But what if we had no idea at all about the cause?  Well, we can always resort to brute force.

Manual experimentation quickly reveals that "Buzz" appears when we scan symbols beginning with "B":

```
ToExpression /@ Names["*`A*"]

(* no "Buzz" *)

ToExpression /@ Names["*`B*"]

(* "Buzz" appears *)
```

We could continue in this fashion using a divide-and-conquer approach to narrow down the range of symbols that could be responsible.  In this case, we will assume that there are not *that* many symbols that start with "B", so let's just print them all out and then look for the "Buzz":

```
Names["*`B*"] // Map[(Print[#]; ToExpression[#]) &]
```

[image: "Buzz"]

There it is, right where we found it before in `` GeneralUtilities`Buzz ``.

Comment: It's seen some copy error in `info`?

Comment: What error are you seeing?  The definition as written works for me (using V11.0.1).  I do not see a missing `&` in the definition (it uses an explicit `Function[...]` form).

Comment: Sorry,I forget to `Clear` to the old version maybe.And your answer  amazing me again. :)

Comment: Can you show me *how do you find* that ``"CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`AbsorbNumbers"`` cause that?And that **Buzz** ？

Comment: See the new section on _Debugging Tricks_.

Comment: Wow,thanks for your this edit...

Comment: BTW,have you see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133403/21532)?

Comment: I have now.  +1 :)

Comment: Actually for [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125388/21532),then dig out of that. :)

Comment: But in the end,can we get a list of that functions cannot ToExpression?

Comment: I think the answer is "no" for all intents and purposes.  As I noted in my response, the only way to really tell is to actually evaluate all the names.  And that will cause all kinds of harmful side-effects.  I advise against it, but if one is brave: `$bad = Cases[Names["*`*"], 
 n_ /; CheckAll[Quiet@Check[ToExpression@n; False, True], 
   0 != Length@Last@{##} || # &]]`.  Be prepared to dismiss many pop-up dialogs and wait a very long time... assuming the expression even finishes without crashing the kernel or running out of memory.

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach is to use [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html) to see if a Symbol is considered to have a value.  (Caveat: this still causes evaluation as is the subject of [Implementing a safe ValueQ that does not evaluate its argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/121).)

Because many Symbols are defined to load additional libraries the first time they are used you will get a lot of false positives the first time this is run, so run it a second time for more useful results.  I use [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) to suppress the messages that would otherwise be generated.

```
Cases[
 ToHeldExpression @ Names["*`*"],
 Hold[s_Symbol] /; Quiet @ ValueQ @ s :> HoldForm[s]
]
```

> ```
> {AASTriangle, DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`Aberration, AbortKernels, 
> NIntegrate`AbscissasWeightsIntegration, 
> Statistics`Library`AbsoluteCorrelationDefinition, AbsoluteCorrelationFunction, 
> RandomProcesses`Library`AbsoluteCorrelationFunctionFromSlices, 
> TemporalData`AbsoluteDuration, . . . }
> ```

If you describe the motivation behind this question I might be able to refine this result.