# What does $UseTextSearchQ do?

Tags: bugs, undocumented, built-in-symbols

Mathematica 11.2 features a new built-in symbol in the `` Global` `` context:

```
Global`$UseTextSearchQ
```

What does it do, and how do I use it?

I tried setting `` Global`$UseTextSearchQ `` to different values, but I didn't understand how it works.

It apparently has some underlying code according to `PrintDefinitions`:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[Global`$UseTextSearchQ]
```

> ```
> Global`$UseTextSearchQ[___][___] := <<kernel function>>;
> ```

Comment: As Szabolcs says in his answer, it's a bug, and I have tagged it as such.

Comment: I have claimed it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129978/21532)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. There should be no symbols in `` Global` `` at startup.

`PrintDefinitions` saying that it has a definition is also a bug.  In this version it claims that every single symbol has a builtin subvalue.

Comment: Yeah, but every release seems to come with some symbols defined in the `Global` context at start-up. Different ones in each new release. Perhaps WRI pre-release testing should add a test for this.

Comment: @m_goldberg I've reported bugs like this multiple times ... it's strange they haven't added an automated test for it yet.

Comment: V11.1.1 starts up with a clean `Global` context -- kind of makes it stand out among recent releases.

Comment: I have claimed it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129978/21532)